# Criando componentes em Run Time em Serviço do Windows

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Estou tentando fazer um *Serviço do Windows* no *Delphi 10.2* e em umas das `procedure` eu preciso criar um `TMemo` só que quando executo da esse erro abaixo.

> ```
> Project AutoPub.exe raised exception class EInvalidOperation with
> message 'Control 'TMemo($043A90C0)' has no parent window. Path:
> TServiceApplication($03164E50)
> .svcAutoPub <br>
> .TMemo($043A90C0)'
> ```

vou por o trecho onde ocorre o erro.

```
procedure TsAutoPub.GetPublicacoes(var Nome: string; Token, Cod: string; Periodo: TDate);
var
  Data: string;
begin
  Data := StringReplace(DateToStr(Date()),'/','-',[rfReplaceAll]);

==> MemoJson := TMemo.Create; // Aqui onde da o erro!!

  GETRequest.Params.Items[0].Value := NomeRelacional;
  GETRequest.Params.Items[1].Value := Token;
  GETRequest.Params.Items[2].Value := CodEscritorio;
  GETRequest.Params.Items[3].Value := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', Periodo);
  GETRequest.Params.Items[4].Value := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', Periodo);

  try
    try
      GETRequest.Execute;
    finally
      MemoJson.Lines.Clear;
      MemoJson.Lines.Add('{"Publicações":'+#13+GETResponse.JSONText+'}');

      if not DirectoryExists(tbParametosPASTA_BD.AsString+'\Publicações') then
       CreateDir(tbParametosPASTA_BD.AsString+'\Publicações');

      MemoJson.Lines.SaveToFile('C:\Autosad\Banco\Publicações - '+Data+'.json');
    end;
  except on E: ERESTException do
     ShowMessage(IntToStr(GETResponse.StatusCode) + ':' + GETResponse.StatusText);
  end;
end;
```

Queria saber como criar essa `TMemo` no *serviço do windows* de maneira correta.
ou onde etá o erro no código.

Comment: Como dito pelo Leonardo Getulio, utilize o `TStrings` que servirá para o seu propósito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um serviço do Delphi não consegue criar um TMemo pelo fato dele ser um componente gráfico e precisa de um "parent" desenhado para se desenhar dentro dele.

A solução mais correta no seu caso para manipular estes textos seria utilizar TStrings ou TStringList. Particularmente prefiro TStringList. As substituições no caso ficariam assim:

```
var
  MemoJson: TStringList; 

//
MemoJson := TStringList.Create();
MemoJson.Clear;
MemoJson.Add('{"Publicações":'+#13+GETResponse.JSONText+'}');
MemoJson.SaveToFile();
```

Comment: Opa!
Vou fazer os teste aqui... Não me liguei nessa questão de componente gráfico.

Comment: Até funciona mais na hora que vou gravar o .pdf o texto sai em uma linha e fica horrível.
o iria fica como variável nem vai ser desenhado...

Comment: Consegui resolver de outro modo.